# How can I get the reference of map fragment object in a popup window?

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, popupwindow

I'm having a base activity which has one fragment showing map on complete screen.

On top of this, I show another list. In the list, each item has a detail button. When it is clicked, I show a popup window with details. The popup window has a map fragment inside.

How can I reference this map object to add a custom marker?

Comment: show us some code.. where you stuck..  what you need.. explain by showing what you done,,

Comment: As previously mentioned, how can we get the object of map support fragment when the inflated layout is used inside a popup window? findViewById or getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById, seems they can't be used to get the map reference

Comment: Use callback to pass data from your fragment to activity
like this :

    class A implements ICallback {
     MyObject o;
     B b = new B(this, someParameter);

     @Override
     public void callback(MyObject o){
           this.o = o;
     }
}

class B {
     ICallback ic;
     B(ICallback ic, someParameter){
         this.ic = ic;
     }

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
             // some calculation
             ic.callback(myObject)
         }
    }).start(); 
}

interface ICallback(){
    public void callback(MyObject o);
}
'